# what does preposition "in" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> When police officers tried to push the crowds back, older men and
> women refused to back off and shouted **in** officers’ faces.

as far as I know,the patttern "A in B" usually means that A is inside of B.
but concerning the question as meantioned,this pattern obviously doesn't pertain in the phrase "shouted in officers's face".
so what does "in" mean in "shouted in officers's face"?

Comment: maybe similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62042/difference-between-at-someones-face-vs-in-someones-face-vs-to-someones-f)

Comment: If someone _shouts in your face_, they stand so that their face is very close to yours.